# Why won't this Excel autoformat work: ="$G5<max(I5:AB5)"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make the cell change color when any one of a range of cells is greater than its valve.  This seems like pretty simple code to me, but when I test it out, the cell doesn't change color.  It is first on the list to execute, so I'm sure its not being superseded by other formatting.

My "Format values where this is true:" has the following:

```
="$G5<max(I5:AB5)"
```

This code is also not working:

```
="int(isblank(F$5))=1"
```

Comment: `F$5` looks wrong to me. Did you mean `$F5`?

Comment: Do you actually have quotes in there? Take them out.

Comment: don't worry about this one, I just found a much easier way to highlight blanks.
="int(isblank(F$5))=1"

Comment: Do you need INT for the blank check? Try just `=ISBLANK(F$5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where conditional formatting shines. Click on the array you want to highlight. Click on Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Greater Than. In the box that appears **type in**

```
=MAX(I5:AB5)
```

and hit enter. That's it, they should turn red right away! (assuming you chose red as the color)